# FieldName underscore corrupts Label Expression for Font Size

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, font

I am trying to change the size of a secondary line in the Label Expression box:

> MID( [TRACT] ,4,11) & vbnewline & [FERC_NAME]

This approach does not work but it DOES work when the field name is something like TRACT.

> "" & [FERC_NAME] & ""

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using ArcGIS for Desktop, in Labels>Expression>Help section states that you need concatenate HTML tags with field specifiers to be able to do such tricks:

> Specify a conditional if-else statement. These functions label cities
>   with their name in a large, red font if their population is equal to
>   or exceeds 250,000 and in the default label font if the population is
>   less than 250,000:

`Python`

```py
def FindLabel ( [NAME], [POPULATION] ):
  if long([POPULATION]) >= 250000:
    return "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '14'>" + [NAME] + "</FNT></CLR>"
  else:
    return [NAME]
```

`VBScript`

```vbs
Function FindLabel ([NAME], [POPULATION])
  if (cLng([POPULATION]) >= 250000) then
   FindLabel = "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '14'>" + [NAME] + "</FNT></CLR>"
  else
     FindLabel = [NAME]
  end if
End Function
```

`JScript`

```js
function FindLabel ( [NAME], [POPULATION]  )
{
if (parseFloat([POPULATION]) >= 250000){
return ("<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '14'>" + [NAME] + "</FNT></CLR>");
}
else
return ([NAME]);
}
```